# Why is it not recommended to switch a React component from controlled to uncontrolled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React warns if you you convert a component from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa) during the lifecycle of components.

Besides this being confusing to reason about, are there other technical reasons for which this is not recommended ?

Comment: Can you please share a sample code that reproduces this warning? Which version of ReactJS are you using?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/markerikson/d71cfc81687f11609d2559e8daee10cc basically everything you need to know why

Comment: That gist only describes why react has controlled form inputs. That information is already available from the official documentation. I am looking for a realistic-ish case where switching from controlled to uncontrolled (or vv) will lead to an erroneous outcome - input getting out of sync with state or a race condition or likewise.

Comment: @KaloyanKosev Fiddle with react 15.4.2 :  https://jsfiddle.net/wy5tceo6/ If you type anything in the input you will get the warning.

Comment: @lorefnon thank you for the jsfiddle! I believe the main reason is to prevent confusion and unexpected behavior (and therefore - bugs). I shared my experience and why I think so in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43056999/1333836).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, I believe the main reason is to prevent **confusion** and **unexpected behavior** (and therefore - *bugs*).

This warning came since ReactJS 15. In the previous major version - React 14 (technically, React 0.14) - there wasn't such warning.

Therefore, here's a popular misconception which illustrates a possible confusion. I [forked your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/superKalo/eofzc680/) and did the following changes:

- switched to ReactJS to 14 (technically, React 0.14)
- I added values for both `value` (empty string) and `defaultValue` ('hello').

No console warnings anymore. Here's the misconception: one might think that the default (initial) value will be 'hello' and then -> since the Input is controlled -> all future value changes will be stored inside the component state.

**But that's not the case**. The default displayed value is an empty string, not 'hello'. Believe me, for developers which struggle to grasp the idea behind controlled inputs, that will cause confusion. I've experienced it myself!

Therefore, switching back to React 15, you get a nice little warning:

> Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

It doesn't tell you the full story **why**, but at least it directs you *where* to read and *how* to solve it. Much better than no warning at all, right? :-)

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer the question asked: Switching back and forth from controlled to uncontrolled is not using the tool as intended and could cause some strange behaviors. As you mention, it would make it hard to understand what is actually happening (which as a programmer, you should be trying to avoid that type of code). Furthermore, I can't think of an instance where switching back and forth is needed or desired. Do you have any examples of where you need this?

---

There are a few things to note here. If you open the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wy5tceo6/) from your comment, you'll notice two warning messages pop up immediately:

> Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using
>   the empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for
>   uncontrolled components.
>
> Warning: FormPresenter contains an input of type text with both value
>   and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or
>   uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop,
>   but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input
>   element and remove one of these props.

Putting the jsx here for reference:

```
  <input 
    type="text" 
     value={this.state.value} 
     defaultValue={this.state.defaultValue}
     onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
```

The first warning is telling you there's something wrong with what you're passing as a value, and is why it gives you the error you're asking about (more on this in a minute).

The second warning is telling you that controlled components should only use `value` and uncontrolled components should only use `defaultValue`. The reason here is if you need to set a default value for a controlled component, you can just default the value you pass to `value`. And if you're using an uncontrolled component you only care about setting a default value as you want the browser to manage the current value normally.

So, now when you type in the input, it gives you that third warning:

> Warning: FormPresenter is changing an uncontrolled input of type text
>   to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled
>   to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

This is linked to the first warning. Because you're defaulting `this.state.value` to `null`, the `input` is not considered controlled. If you change the default to an empty string (`''`), you're properly controlling the input and will not get the warning message. [jsfiddle updated to show this](https://jsfiddle.net/wy5tceo6/1/)

Comment: The question is not how is to be resolved, but what kind problems it may cause.

Comment: Ah, I'll update it a bit - I got sidetracked on the errors.

Comment: "The reason here is if you need to set a default value for a controlled component, you can just default the value you pass to value" This is so week conclusion. I have default as an empty string and I would like for the numeric component to start from some default number. Now I am getting those errors.

Comment: @IevgenNaida why not default it to a number instead of an empty string? `value={myValue || "0"}` or something similar

Comment: @JamesGanong in this case you cannot have '' as default. So you cannot have all 3 states: empty, default wen focused and entered.

Comment: @IevgenNaida Why do you need 3 states? You could use onFocus to update the value when focused (if empty), which allows you to have empty when first rendered, default value on focus, and entered value when changed.

Comment: @James Ganong usecase is simple like, undefined state means app will decide on value (imagine something like inherited in css). But when you really about to enter something than it's should start from the known value. The usecase it's not very common but anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You might have been using an input field with both properties "value={variable1}" & "defaultValue={something}". like this -->

```
<input 
value={mobile}
onChange={(e) => setMobile(e.target.value)} 
type="text"
defaultValue="XXXXXXXXXX"
/>
```

just remove defaultValue attribute. like this -->

```
<input 
value={mobile}
onChange={(e) => setMobile(e.target.value)} 
type="text"
/>
```

That's it. Happy Coding.